# How to file income tax for administratively dissolved S-Corp still getting money from contracting work?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

I have an S-Corp which I just realized was administratively dissolved in 2011. But I have been using a bank account linked with the S-Corp to get contracting income.

I have filed 1040 schedule C for 2012, 2013 & 2014 under S-Corp's name and EIN number. Now I am not sure what to do for year 2015? I talked with my accountant and he is saying don't use S-Corp's name any more; just file 2015 taxes under your SSN. But question is: I got all the payments for year 2015 under my company name; can I still file taxes under my SSN?

Comment: Seems like the question now is not about how you should file your taxes but whether you were clear to cash checks made out to an entity that no longer exists....

Comment: @Brick - I been getting my checks cleared for last 4 years. I dont know what to do now? Any suggestions?

Comment: You had a related earlier question, no? Advice is still the same: Get professional help on this one. You're probably technically afoul of a few laws at the state level and the federal level. If you didn't intend to defraud (sounds like you didn't), then you'll *probably* slide by with minimal action on your part as long as you stop doing the wrong things now that you know they are wrong. At the same time, a professional versed in your jurisdiction's laws will know much more specifically what to do. Note state laws very a lot on some issues, so you cannot use generic advice on that part.